# How long does a GPS almanac last for a quick fix within cold start?

Tags: gps, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini and did two tests, both with cold GPS start (without A-GPS data):

1. starting GPS receiver 11 hours after last fix - got new fix almost instantly (30 seconds)
2. starting GPS receiver 23 hours after last fix - could not fix in 10-15 minutes (did not count exactly)

I have to mention the GPS was turned on in Android system between last fix and test and phone was on wifi. My question is - how long do GPS almanac data last for a quite quick (say under 3 minutes) cold start?

Comment: Were you in the same location for #1 and #2?

Comment: Yes, same location.

Comment: According to the USCG (page 55), [GPS almanac data is valid for 180 days](http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/pubs/gps/gpsuser/gpsuser.pdf).

Comment: Apps like [GPS Status and Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) will let you know the current age of your device's GPS almanac and force a download of a fresh almanac if you're worried about that being the problem.

Comment: Yes I use GPS Status app... actually forcing to download the almanac helped in the case #2 I think.